# Using MSChart, add a datapoint to a stacked column

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I have a stacked column ms chart in which all charts have 3 series / values.  If a certain condition exists, I would like to add an additional series to the chart. In the image below, the additional series on the chart appears at the first and second indexed column.  I would like the additional stacked column to appear on the 2nd and 9th position.  Any idea on how I would do this?

[image]

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            { 
                // Populate series data
                Random  random = new Random();
                for(int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
                {

                    Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(10);
                    Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddY(50);
                    Chart1.Series[2].Points.AddY(30);

                    if (pointIndex == 1 || pointIndex == 8)
                    {
                        //both commented out code blocks break chart
                        //Chart1.Series[3].Points.AddXY(40,pointIndex);
                        //Chart1.Series[3].Points.AddXY(pointIndex,40);

                        Chart1.Series[3].Points.AddXY(0,40);//.AddXY(0,40);
                    }


                }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the series needs to be aligned correctly. So you should enter empty Data points where you do not need points. Example

```
if (pointIndex == 1 || pointIndex == 8)
{
  Chart1.Series[3].Points.AddY(40);
}
else
{
  Chart1.Series[3].Points.Add( new DataPoint() { IsEmpty = true } );
}
```